# Store multiple emails, fax, mobile and address

Tags: mysql

I am  aware that this question is asked before and common solution would be like in this link. Separate tables and use join to get information

[How to store multiple emails work, personal etc for one contact in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494429/how-to-store-multiple-emails-work-personal-etc-for-one-contact-in-mysql)

I just want ask is there any drawback if i saved comma separated emails, numbers, fax or address . This will also eliminate Joins hence better performance. Thanks in advance

Comment: 'hence better performance' ? Perhaps you know more than us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any database-driven application, it's helpful to ask: "What questions does my application need the database to answer?" In other words, what are the main use cases for querying?

The link you provide is basically an example of normalized relational database architecture. Normal forms are meant to minimize duplicate data and ensure data integrity. Within those "quality-control constraints," query-writing is supposed to be fairly patterned and predictable.

Will you need to know if a contact has duplicate email or phone numbers? If multiple contacts share the same email or contact? If phone1 is missing but phone2 is not missing? If all the phone numbers have international prefixes? Those are all questions that can be answered with a database query. And those queries would be *much easier* and *much more straightforward* to write with a normalized database (like the one in the link). With data in a single field of comma-separated values, the queries would be hard, impractical, ugly, or virtually impossible to manage.